# Do the Generators of integral de Rham Cohomology always integrate to 1?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\omega$ be the Fubini-Study-Form on complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$, normalized s.t. $\int_{\mathbb{P}^1}\omega =1$, and let $1\leq n\leq N$.
Then $\int_{\mathbb{P}^n}\omega^n =1$. I've seen a differential geometry proof for that.

But I want to ask about the **connection to de Rham cohomology**.
Is it true, that
    \begin{align*}
 \int_{\mathbb{P}^1}\omega =1 \Leftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{P}^n}\omega^n =1 \Leftrightarrow \omega \text{ generator of } H^2\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right)?
 \end{align*}

**My ideas so far**: (using Mumford's Algebraic Geometry I as a reference for de Rham cohomology)

The $2n$-form $\omega^{n}$ is a basis of $H^{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right)$.
For the homology, $H_{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and is generated by the fundamental class $[\mathbb{P}^n]$ (the image of $\mathbb{P}^n$ under the homomorphism $H_{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{Z}\right)\rightarrow H_{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right)$).

Maybe because we have the bilinear map
    \begin{align*}
 H^{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right) \times H_{2n}\left(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathbb{Z}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
 \end{align*}
the basis element of the cohomology space $\omega^n$ is mapped to a generator/ basis element of the image and the image is $\mathbb{Z}$? 
Maybe we can use the duality of the two spaces in some sense?
I also tried using de Rham's Theorem, but it only made sense for a topdimensional form, which is not of interest here.

Comment: We know the cup-product structure on $H^*(\mathbb{P}^N;\mathbb{Z})$, namely it is a polynomial ring in one variable with degree 2 and truncated above degree $N$, and we know that the inclusion $\mathbb{P}^k \to \mathbb{P}^N$ induces a cohomology isomorphism in degrees $< N$. We also know that the homomorphism $H^*(\mathbb{P}^N;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^*(\mathbb{P}^N;\mathbb{R})$ is injective and its image is the cohomology classes whose integrals are integers. I think the result you want follows from these facts.

Comment: edit: I should have said "truncated above degree $2N$" and "isomorphism in degrees $\leq 2k$"

Comment: how does it help to have a polynomial ring? interesting tho. I just don't see the connection to the evaluation of the integral being $1$